# Visual Studio's AngularJS Template Explained

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2015, angularjs-controller, angularjs-injector, self-invoking-function

When I create a new controller using VS2015 templates I get this code:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('controller', controller);

    controller.$inject = ['$scope']; 

    function controller($scope) {
        $scope.title = 'controller';

        activate();

        function activate() { }
    }
})();
```

**Questions:**

1. Why does VS template wraps the code in a self invocing function?
2. What's the thing with the `activate()` function? What code do I suppose to write inside and why do I need a seperate function instead of just writing the code inside the controller?
3. Do the `controller.$inject = ['$scope'];` considered a better practice then writing the dependencies in an array (as an argument of the controller function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does VS template wraps the code in a self invoking function?

Because it prevents corrupting global namespace. In this case, `controller` will become a member of global namespace in the absence of IIFE.

> What's the thing with the `activate()` function?

It helps separating declaration and execution of controller variables and code respectively. Prior to calling the `activate` function, we usually declare all the dependencies as the controller members using `this.` syntax.

You will write the executing code inside the `activate` function.

> Do the `controller.$inject = ['$scope'];` considered a better practice?

Actually yes! It helps you to separate your controller definition from it's angular counterpart. It helps you to avoid writing the entire controller code in `angular.module( ... ).controller` block to improve readability of your code.

**Edit 1**:

Without the IIFE, the function named `controller` will become a member of the global namespace, and will be accessible throughout your page. It will also pose a possiblity of being overwritten by subsequent code. Don't mix AngularJS with this, because this is something which JavaScript does.

The `activate` function is just a layer to separate the concerns. You can write your code entirely in the function `controller`. But in that way, it becomes harder to separate which code controller is executing, and which code binds the variables to controller. Take this example:

```
function controller($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.data = [];
  $scope.title = 'controller';

  activate();

  ///
  function activate() {
    getData()
      .then(data => {
        // do something with data
      });

    // ...
  }

  function getData() {
    ...
  }
}
```

By reading the above code, one can easily know about the variables being used down the line in the controller, without specifically going into the depth of the controller. By following this convention, we will always know that the controller will start executing the business logic right where `activate()` is called.

Comment: Exactly, Good precise answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'll appreciate if you could elaborate regarding - 1.Why the controller becomes a member of the global namespace without the IIFE? Does angular magically "attaches" the instance of the controller to the scope it's defined in? And where does angular attach it when I do use IIFE? 2.Regarding the activate function - could you please add a small code sample to illustrate what goes inside the activate function and what outside of it? (it seems to me that all my controller code was always 'declarations' of variables/functions which I add to scope/controller..)

Comment: @BornToCode -- Please see the updated answer. I hope this will help you understand it better.

Comment: So if I compare it to C# so the activate() is like a constructor and the "class members" are defined before the activate, right?
 If I understand correctly this line `angular.module('app').controller('controller', controller);` just defines a controller which will be initiated when a view with the ng-controller="controller" is loaded, I'm missing the angular magic part when does it "stick it" to the global namespace and where does it "stick it" when I use IIFE?

Comment: @BornToCode -- As I mentioned, you can write the entire logic without using `activate` at all. But yes, just to resemble constructor-like function, this is in place.